# Unable to extract date(Y,M,D) from function

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm an extreme beginner at Prolog (SWI-Prolog, to be specific), and I'm having a lot of trouble getting the current weekday, although I have been able to get the current year, month, and day number just fine.

```
currentDate(Today) :-
    get_time(Stamp),
    stamp_date_time(Stamp,DateTime,local),
    date_time_value(date,DateTime,Today).

currentWeekday(Wday) :- day_of_the_week(currentDate(_Today), Wday).
```

When I just run `currentDate(Today)` in the console, I get

```
Today = date(2016, 11, 30).
```

So I am getting a `date()` object (or whatever you call it) as far as I can tell. But when I try to run `currentWeekday(W)` in the console, it just returns `false.`

Comment: Are you trying to run `currentWeekday(w)` or `currentWeekday(W)`?

Comment: currentWeekday(W) <- capital letter. Thanks for catching that. I've edited the description.

Comment: The code works fine for me.  `?- currentDate(W).` gives me `W = date(2016, 12, 1).`

Comment: Seriously? What the heck...

Comment: Wait. No, the problem isn't with currentDate(), it's with currentWeekday(). currentDate() works fine for me too.

Comment: Also, if I manually enter a date, as in run `day_of_the_week(date(2016,12,1),D)` I get `W = 4`. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this predicate:

```
currentWeekday(Wday) :- day_of_the_week(currentDate(_Today), Wday).
```

You're anticipating that Prolog works like an imperative language as if `currentDate(_Today)` returns a value, and that you're passing that value in to `day_of_the_week`. Prolog doesn't work that way. You have to think in terms of unification. Try this:

```
currentWeekday(Wday) :- currentDate(Today), day_of_the_week(Today, Wday).
```

It's important to note what calling `day_of_the_week(currentDate(_Today), Wday)` actually means. It is calling a predicate `day_of_the_week/2` with the first parameter being `currentDate(_Today)`. This parameter is simply a structure - it's not evaluated in any way. That's why when you call `day_of_the_week(date(2016,12,1),D)` it works - you are passing in, as the first parameter, the structure `date(2016,12,1)` and the predicate is able to unify against that value.

NB: there is no "date object" - it's just a structure that looks like `date(2016,12,1)`. You could make a structure in Prolog that looks like `foo(bar(42),wee(Zip))` - that structure is effectively a tree.

Comment: Thank you thank you! My next step was to try something like what you said, but for the life of me I couldn't figure out how to do it. Now I realize I was just over thinking how to unify.

Comment: And thanks also for the additional explanation at the end.